# Count the repeats of foreign key of two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables Countries( id, country) and Cities (id, city, countryId ) I want to select countries  and to show how much cities AS locations .

I tried this :

```
SELECT countryid, COUNT(*) AS locations
FROM Cities 
GROUP BY countryid
```

but it shows me countryid instead of country

Comment: Join with Country Table and get Country value from the Country Table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables as follows:

```
select c.country, count(*) as locations
from Country c
inner join Cities ci
on c.id = ci.countryId
group by c.id, c.country
```

I also included the country in the group by since it appears in the select clause

Comment: Glad I could help c: Would you mind accepting my answer?